# Hibernate foreign key is null

Tags: hibernate

I have 2 tables and here is the entities.

Now,When I insert into the table, the foreign key in the employee_address table is null. Other values are inserted correctly.

Employee

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Employee")
//@NamedQuery(name="Employee.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM Employee e")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private Timestamp created;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dob;

    private String email;

    @Column(name="FATHER_NAME")
    private String fatherName;

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    private String married;

    @Column(name="MOTHER_NAME")
    private String motherName;

    private String telephone;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to EmployeeAddress
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="employee", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<EmployeeAddress> employeeAddresses;
```

EmployeeAddress

```
@Table(name="employee_address")
@NamedQuery(name="EmployeeAddress.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM EmployeeAddress e")
public class EmployeeAddress implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String apt_no;

    private String city;

    private String country;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="create_dt")
    private Date createDt;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="end_dt")
    private Date endDt;

    private String state;

    private String street_addr;

    private String zip_Code;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Employee
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="emp_id")
    private Employee employee;
```

Comment: Add the code which you use to insert. The `employee` association is nullable (not mandatory) and you probably save the address before the employee.

Comment: isn't my idea or an @OrderColumn is missing from the one-to-many part?